# Facebook chat using fbcmd

Tags: facebook, command-line, terminal

I was trying to find out how to chat on facebook using linux terminal. After doing some search I stumbled upon this CLI for facebook known as fbcmd. I installed it and did a lot of things like posting, reading my inbox. I was just wondering if it can be used for chatting also. Is it possible to chat on the linux terminal using fbcmd?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, according to [this](http://fbcmd.dtompkins.com/help/faq#TOC-Can-I-send-messages-send-emails-), you cannot. I researched a lot on this topic and could only find [ekg2](https://github.com/ekg2/ekg2) and [MCabber](http://mcabber.com/) which would suit my purpose.